# MySQL - Modify/Populate table Data based on database view

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring boot and Mysql application. For one of the pages, I am fetching data from a view called all_inventory. The view is complex and contains dynamic sorting on multiple tables and columns.
Problem is, with amount of data increasing, page load time is increasing exponentially.

To improve page load, I created an intermediate table call all_inventory_table and planning to populate data from view into table using scheduled stored procedure. Spring will read this table instead of view hence improved performance.

There are two possibilities

1. Something changed towards the end of the view results. In this case, I will just insert the new records to all_inventory_table that are present in view but not in table
2. Something changed in centre of view results. In this case, I will truncate the table and dump entire data from view to table.

My question is

What is the best way to check what changed in the view results. Basically, I want to add trigger to the view but MySQL doesn't support it. I tried writing select queries using joins but its taking a lot of time to execute.

Also, I cannot write trigger to underlying tables because underlying table will not know if change is toward end of view results or in centre of view results.

Below is the view for information

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW all_inventory
AS
  SELECT row_number()
           over (
             ORDER BY tx.date desc, tx.type desc, tx.keyid desc) as id,
         tx.type,
         tx.keyid,
         tx.entryid,
         tx.date, -- index
         tx.contactid,
         tx.warehouseid,
         tx.Productid,
         tx.quantity,
         tx.closingstock,
         tx.creationDate,
         tx.lastModifiedDate,
         tx.Product_name, -- index
         tx.category_name, -- index
         tx.measurementunit,
         c.name,
         c.mobileno,
         c.emailid,
         c.contacttype,
         tx.warehouse_id,
         tx.warehousename -- index
  FROM   (SELECT 'Inward'                         AS type,
                 ii.inwardid                      as keyid,
                 ioe.entryid                      as entryid,
                 Date_format(ii.DATE, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date,
                 ii.contactid                     AS contactid,
                 ii.warehouse_id                  AS warehouseid,
                 ioe.Productid                    AS Productid,
                 ioe.quantity,
                 ioe.closingstock,
                 ioe.creationDate,
                 ioe.lastModifiedDate,
                 p.Product_name,
                 cat.category_name,
                 p.measurementunit,
                 w.warehouse_id,
                 w.warehousename
          FROM   inward_inventory ii
                 inner join inwardinventory_entry iie
                         ON ii.inwardid = iie.inwardid
                 inner join inward_outward_entries ioe
                         ON iie.entryid = ioe.entryid
                 inner join Product p
                         on p.Productid = ioe.Productid
                 INNER JOIN Category cat
                         on p.categoryId = cat.categoryId
                 inner join Warehouse w
                         ON w.warehouse_id = ii.warehouse_id
          WHERE  ii.is_deleted = 0
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Outward'                        AS type,
                 oi.outwardid                     as keyid,
                 ioe.entryid                      as entryid,
                 Date_format(oi.DATE, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date,
                 oi.contactid                     AS contactid,
                 oi.warehouse_id                  AS warehouseid,
                 ioe.Productid                    AS Productid,
                 ioe.quantity,
                 ioe.closingstock,
                 ioe.creationDate,
                 ioe.lastModifiedDate,
                 p.Product_name,
                 cat.category_name,
                 p.measurementunit,
                 w.warehouse_id,
                 w.warehousename
          FROM   outward_inventory oi
                 inner join outwardinventory_entry oie
                         ON oi.outwardid = oie.outwardid
                 inner join inward_outward_entries ioe
                         ON oie.entryid = ioe.entryid
                 inner join Product p
                         on p.Productid = ioe.Productid
                 INNER JOIN Category cat
                         on p.categoryId = cat.categoryId
                 inner join Warehouse w
                         ON w.warehouse_id = oi.warehouse_id
          WHERE  oi.is_deleted = 0
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Lost-Damaged'                    AS type,
                 lostdamagedid                     as keyid,
                 lostdamagedid                     as entryid,
                 Date_format(ldi.DATE, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date,
                 ''                                AS contactid,
                 ldi.warehousename                 AS warehouseid,
                 ldi.Productid                     AS Productid,
                 ldi.quantity,
                 ldi.closingstock,
                 ldi.creationDate,
                 ldi.lastModifiedDate,
                 p.Product_name,
                 cat.category_name,
                 p.measurementunit,
                 w.warehouse_id,
                 w.warehousename
          FROM   lost_damaged_inventory ldi
                 inner join Product p
                         on p.Productid = ldi.Productid
                 INNER JOIN Category cat
                         on p.categoryId = cat.categoryId
                 inner join Warehouse w
                         ON w.warehouse_id = ldi.warehousename
          where  ldi.is_deleted = 0) AS tx
         left join contacts c
                ON c.contactid = tx.contactid;
```

Comment: I assume 1L is 100K?  (Most Americans don't know about Lakh and Crore.)

Comment: Thanks Rick. That information was of no use and was confusing. So I edited and removed it

Comment: Thanks.  The size of a table is _sometimes_ useful.  But 30K vs 100K is not likely to make any difference in the analysis.  5 lakh versus 5 crore _might_ be important in an analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Start by rearranging things.  It seems that each of the inner Selects joins to `Warehouse` to get the name just to get the `warehousename`.  So, remove those inner Joins and move one copy to the outer select.  (`Contacts` already works that way.)  (Perhaps some other Joins could similarly be rearranged?)

That and most of the following are aimed at speeding up the query.  Though it may not get you to the goal of somehow doing "updates", it is probably worth doing.

Do you really need the `ROW_NUMBER`?  It adds to the complexity and *may* be the most costly part of the query.

Some of these indexes *may* help with performance:

```
ii:  INDEX(is_deleted, inwardid,  `DATE`, contactid, warehouse_id)
oi:  INDEX(is_deleted, outwardid, `DATE`, contactid, warehouse_id)
ldi:  INDEX(is_deleted, Productid)
```

To go any further, we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (to understand, at least, the indexes) and what you need "updating".

If `ii.DATE` is of type `DATE`, then simplify `Date_format(ii.DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")` to `ii.DATE`.  If it is of type `DATETIME`, then simplify to `DATE(ii.DATE)`.

As for making the View updatable (or some other desired path to your goal), ponder how to write the minimal `VIEW`, focusing *only* on gathering the data that leads to the update.  *Then* see if that can be the basis of the big View you showed us.